# Kotlin : how to resolve, "Could not create plugin of type 'KotlinPluginWrapper'?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

**UPDATE RESOLVED!**
I had to update gradle to the latest version.

I am trying to "deploy" a Kotlin project to a standalone server an am running in to the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file '/root/Arctix/build.gradle' line: 4
    
    * What went wrong:
    An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.6.10']
    > Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm']
       > Could not create plugin of type 'KotlinPluginWrapper'.
          > kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
```

I don't understand. Below is my gradle.build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10'
}

group 'dev.j3ee'
version '0.001'

application {
    mainClassName = 'test.MainKt'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.h2database:h2:2.1.210"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Any which way would be amazing. Thank you.

**Resolved**
Update Gradle! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can add an answer to your own question so that others can profit from your experience. Some more information might be helpful as well, for example which version of Gradle resulted in the problem and with which one it no longer occurrs.